# git checkout does not undo committed file

Tags: git

I have edited, added and committed some files. When I run:

```
git diff --stat --cached origin/development
```

one of the files shouldn't have been changed and I would like to undo the changes to that one file.

Based on the diagram below I ran:

```
git checkout file_name
```

but:

```
git difftool --cached origin/development
```

still shows the file contains the changes.

How do I undo the changes to the one file and why did `git checkout` not work?

[image]

Comment: [`git diff --cached origin/development`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--cachedltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203) displays the differences between the index and `origin/development`. `git checkout` doesn't touch the index and doesn't modify `origin/development`, therefore there isn't any reason for the outcome of `git diff` to change.

Comment: `git diff --cached` won't display anything if you did indeed commit the file. If the change was added to the index, then `git status` gives a clue. Have you tried `git reset HEAD your-file` for example?

Comment: @customcommander No i was looking at the above diagram and it seemed to imply running git checkout would revert the file back to the working tree, i.e. undo?

Comment: That diagram is incomplete. I wouldn’t put all my understanding on it.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Can you elaborate/is there a diagram you could recommend?

Comment: Not really. I don’t actually think it can be represented in a single diagram.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned, you have committed some files and now you want to unstage those changes.

Assuming the commit as the latest, you can follow these commands:

**1.** `git reset --soft HEAD~1`

**2.** `git reset HEAD .`

Now you have all the files as unstaged.

If you want any specific file unstaged, after executing **`1`**, do like this:

- `git reset HEAD <filename>`

Comment: But i only want the one file reverted?

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you check?

Comment: I ran the git reset HEAD <filename> and then I ran git diff --stat --cached origin/development but the edits are still there

Comment: Can you add ss of the output in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have confused `git diff` and `git show` here.

**You didn't make the commit nor did you stage any changes yet**

Use `git checkout your-file`

**You didn't make the commit yet but you staged the change already**

Use `git reset HEAD your-file`

**You already made the commit**

Make sure you don't have any pending changes (stash them or discard them), copy your commit hash (see COMMIT_HASH) then:

```
git reset HEAD~1
git checkout your-file
git add your-other-file ...
git commit -c COMMIT_HASH
```

Note: this assumes that the commit is the top of your branch

*If your commit isn't the top of your branch, I'd recommend getting familiar with interactive rebase if and only if you're not touching a public branch. i.e don't rewrite public history.*

Comment: When I run git status it says I am ahead of origin/development by 6 commits. I wanted to see what work I had done, so I ran git diff --stat --cached origin/development. A couple of these files should never have been changed, so I wanted to undo the changes.

Comment: @user997112 I got that and I think I gave some initial step to get you started here.

Comment: Apologies, I read your second sentence saying I didn't commit and thought "wtf"

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing parameter in your `git checkout` command where you should pass the commit that you want to revert the file to, for example:

```
> git log

commit 11111
Date:  today

    File broken

commit 22222
Date:  yesterday

    File working fine
```

Then revert the changes to your file:

```
git checkout 22222 file_name
```

And the changes will be reverted for `file_name` and placed in the staging area:

```
git diff --staged
```